# Static variable set to null and then if statement to check if that variable is null

Tags: php

I just want to understand what is the purpose of setting static $db variable to null before if statement where it is checked if it's null. Then it will always be null. That's the code for getting PDO database connection from abstract class

```
static $db = null;

if($db === null)
{

    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'framework_test';

    try {
    $db = new PDO..

    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }       
} 
return $db;
```

Comment: It is called initialisation

Comment: It is a singleton. The jist is that you always have just one instance which you access and store it as a static member of the class when it is first used.

Comment: Yes but in the video they said that it's connected only once to database and every time when I call that method again it wont connect to database and the same connection will be used. But if it is initialized every time when that method is called then every time it will connect to database again.

Comment: @user3647971 Where do you see a singleton in this code?

Comment: @Xatenev No where, but I have my reasons to believe this is not all of the code. As mentioned in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this code is inside a function that might be called more often?

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

> Example #5 Example use of static variables

```
<?php
function test()
{
    static $a = 0;
    echo $a;
    $a++;
}
?>
```

> $a is initialized only in first call of function and every time the test() function is called it will print the value of $a and increment it.

Answer (score 0):

It's only going to be `null` *the first time.* The second time `$db` will hold a `PDO` instance and it won't initialise the database connection again. `static` variables keep their values across function invocations, that's what the `static` keyword is for.

The reason you can't directly write `static $db = new PDO(...)` is that `static` variables can only be directly initialised using constant values, not dynamic expressions like `new PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is called Singleton design pattern ,
means where you don't want to create more then one object of a single class.
in your scenario , if you call this function first time the $db is null and then if condition is true then your database connection is made and this connection is store into the $db variable , but when you call that function second time then $db variable has already connection instant on it  , then if condition is fail and your function will return $db without creating the new object of database again.